# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "alglib::spline2dcalc(alglib::spline2dinterpolant const&, double, double, alglib::xparams)"

Tags: c++, macos, alglib

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "interpolation.h"

using namespace alglib;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //
    // We use bilinear spline to interpolate f(x,y)=x^2+2*y^2 sampled 
    // at (x,y) from [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] X [0.0, 1.0].
    //
    real_1d_array x = "[0.0, 0.5, 1.0]";
    real_1d_array y = "[0.0, 1.0]";
    real_1d_array f = "[0.00,0.25,1.00,2.00,2.25,3.00]";
    double vx = 0.25;
    double vy = 0.50;
    double v;
    double dx;
    double dy;
    double dxy;
    spline2dinterpolant s;

    // build spline
    spline2dbuildbicubicv(x, 3, y, 2, f, 1, s);

    // calculate S(0.25,0.50)
    v = spline2dcalc(s, vx, vy);
    printf("%.4f\n", double(v)); // EXPECTED: 1.0625

    // calculate derivatives
    spline2ddiff(s, vx, vy, v, dx, dy, dxy);
    printf("%.4f\n", double(v)); // EXPECTED: 1.0625
    printf("%.4f\n", double(dx)); // EXPECTED: 0.5000
    printf("%.4f\n", double(dy)); // EXPECTED: 2.0000
    return 0;
}
```

**I want to use the alglib to do the bicubic spline interpolation, but when I use**

```
g++ -I /Users/.../Documents/cpp/src -o a test.cpp
```

**to run the code, it comes the eroor like**
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
"alglib::spline2dcalc(alglib::spline2dinterpolant const&, double, double, alglib::xparams)", referenced from:
      _main in ccmNfxlB.o
```

**how could I make it work?**

Comment: Probably you need to link against library, its not enough to include just headers, or if its about header only library you need to define macros for particular environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the appropriate ALGLIB definitions.

**Solution:** Compile ALGLIB's source (.h and .cpp files) to form a static library file and then add it when you call g++ alongside *test.cpp* so the compiler could find and use the missing definitions.

The steps to accomplish that:

First, put all of ALGLIB's source files (.h and .cpp files) into a separate folder, from which you should call:

```
g++ -c *.cpp
ar rcs alglib.a *.o
```

Then, copy the *alglib.a* file to where your *test.cpp* resides, and from there call the compiler again but this time like this:

```
g++ -I /Users/.../Documents/cpp/src -o a test.cpp alglib.a
```

Comment: these really works,thanks for solving my problems!